# Question on the differences in the definitions of what a tensor is

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra, general-relativity

Below are the common definitions of tensor.

a. "a tensor is a quantity which transforms according to a definite law under the change of the coordinate system".

b. "a tensor is a multilinear function which takes vectors and duals and produces a scalar"

Questions:

1. How are these two definitions related? That is, how can we start with one of definitions and arrive at the other?
2. What is the significance of being "multilinear"? If we have a function of vectors & duals producing a scalar which is not multilinear, what breaks down?

The way I have so far understood a tensor is as follows. Multiple vectors might act on each point in space and produce a result. Tensor is a way of describing the whole phenomena. But again, I could not relate this to the definitions. Why "invariance under coordinate change" or "mulitlinearity" are required here?

Comment: To answer question 2, you'll have to tell as a little bit more about the context in which you're using tensors. For instance, are you using tensors for differential geometry? Are you looking at a specific physics application?

Comment: The goal is to study General Relativity and tensors turned out to be a prerequisite for that. And I've encountered this under "stress tensor" as well. Basically, I'm not getting the big picture connection between the ways tensors are explained.

Comment: The first section [here](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/tensors.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: @Ivo That's an impressive write-up you've put together!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks! I struggled just like OP when trying to understand these things, this wasn't being covered in any classes I was taking at the time, and I had to learn it fast. I actually had written it in Portuguese back in 2015 or 2016, and just translated it last year :P

Comment: @SatheeshPaul Proposition 1.8 on page 8 of Ivo's writeup is a good example of an answer to 1. In particular, the rules under which the "tensor quantity" transforms are a direct consequence of what exactly the multilinear map does.

Comment: The correct way to define tensors is via the Tensor Product space. What you have is an example of a "concrete tensor".

Comment: @IvoTerek That's indeed a very clear and concise summary of tensors. I was already fairly familiar with most of the material in the first two sections, but your write up clarified some fine points (especially regarding well definition of trace of various tensors). The final section was very clearly written; for some reason I never really understood many other presentations, but yours was very understandable.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I'm glad you found it useful. Defining tensors via the universal property is definitely the cleanest way, but useless if you want to get comfortable with the computations fast (which is what one needs for geometry and physics, a priori). I wrote the third section mostly for completeness and to avoid algebraists nagging me about it. It's not like I'm saying that even physicists and geometers don't need to get comfortable with the abstract approach, it just should not be their very first contact with the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by making definition a detailed: under general coordinate transformations, a tensor satisfies$$T^{a_1\cdots a_p}_{\qquad b_1\cdots b_q}=\prod_{i=1}^p\frac{\partial x^{a_i}}{\partial y^{A_i}}\cdot\prod_{j=1}^q\frac{\partial y^{B_j}}{\partial x^{b_j}}\cdot T^{A_1\cdots A_p}_{\qquad B_1\cdots B_q}$$(all "products" herein are also [contracted over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)). You can verify the contraction of two tensors is a tensor; you'll just need to use$$\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial y^A}\frac{\partial y^A}{\partial x^b}=\delta^a_b,\,\frac{\partial y^A}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial y^B}=\delta^A_B.$$Therefore, tensors are closed under contracting away all the indices to make a scalar, viz.$$S:=T^{a_1\cdots a_p}_{\qquad b_1\cdots b_q}\prod_iD^{(i)}_{a_i}\prod_jV^{b_j}_{(j)}$$(our duals $D^{(i)}_{a_i}$ and vectors $V_{(j)}^{b_j}$ have bracketed labels that shouldn't be confused with their contractible indices). Then $S$ is invariant under GCTs, showing definition a implies definition b - including, in particular, the multilinearity in the $D$s & $V$s. We can prove the converse using scalars' invariance and the duals' and vectors' behaviour under GCTs,$$D_{a_i}^{(i)}=\frac{\partial y^{A_i}}{\partial x^{a_i}}D_{A_i}^{(i)},\,V^{b_j}_{(j)}=\frac{\partial x^{b_j}}{\partial y^{B_j}}V^{B_j}_{(j)}.$$